# Scroll a div based on a draggable element (reversed)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

i found this code that is scrolling a div via a draggable element. I don't quite understand the posted answer and also i want to do it in reverse.

original here : [Scroll a div based on a draggable element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066277/scroll-a-div-based-on-a-draggable-element)

http://jsfiddle.net/xNLsE/8/

i modified the fiddle and made it to scroll down on load, the original answer works without scrolling the content down.

i added this block for it to scroll down

```
    //modification
var timeline = $('#timeline');
var tlParent = timeline.parent();
var tlHeight = parseInt(timeline.css("height"));
var tlPHeight = parseInt(tlParent.css("height"));

//scroll down the content on load
var newPos = 0 - (tlHeight - tlPHeight);
timeline.animate({"top":newPos + "px"},800,"linear");
//end modification
```

my modification : http://jsfiddle.net/j3toxicat3d/hxBGd/

help anyone? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I battled with this script and got it working in reverse -

```
//modification
var timeline = $('#timeline');
var tlParent = timeline.parent();
var tlHeight = timeline.height();
var tlPHeight = tlParent.height();

//scroll down the content on load
var lastDirection
, newPos = tlHeight - tlPHeight;
$('#timeline_wrapper').animate({scrollTop:newPos + "px"},800,"linear");
//end modification


var $controller = $('#controller')
    , scrollableHeight = $('#timeline').height() - $('#timeline_wrapper').height()
    , draggableWidth = $('#horizontal_control').width() - $controller.width()
    , ratio = scrollableHeight / draggableWidth
    , initialOffset = $controller.offset().left;

$controller.draggable({
    revert: false,
    containment: "parent",
    axis: "x",
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        var distance = ui.offset.left - initialOffset
        , currentPos = $('#timeline_wrapper').scrollTop();
        var direction = ui.position.left;
        (lastDirection < direction) ? $('#timeline_wrapper').scrollTop(currentPos - distance) : $('#timeline_wrapper').scrollTop(currentPos + distance);
        lastDirection = ui.position.left;
    }
});
```

I think you'll notice what I modified.

[Here is a working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rossmartin/hABBR/)

Comment: thanks for giving it some time man. i'll use your modifications and add some more to it. As you can see, in the original, the amount of px you drag also corresponds to the level of scrolling. i think that's one thing that's lacking with your solution.

Comment: @Jetoox Hey np you're welcome.  It became a battle and I just couldn't give up on it, lol.  I have edited the fiddle again a little bit and revised the code in the answer.  It would be ideal to have to completely scroll to the right in order to scroll the text all the way to the top and vice versa... I think you can handle that from here.

Comment: it was also my battle man. if you want, i posted the whole problem as a different question here is stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111683/animate-scroll-up-and-down-a-div-by-a-dragging-an-element